# Run different angular components on different non-SPA pages

Tags: angular

I need to use Angular only in some pages of non-SPA traditional web application (in my case it's Flask python framework + Jinja2 for templates).

The idea is user goes to `/foo`, server returns html that contains **only** `<foo-component></foo-component>` and Angular handles the component.
When user goes to `/bar` server returns html that contains only `<bar-component></bar-component>`. And so on.

My initial thought was that I'll just list all my "page components" as root components in `app.module.ts` (because they are root components), but it turns out that in that case angular requires all root components to be declared in the html at once.

*How to design the bootstrapping process to make described use case possible?*

One way would be to render single root component and let it decide which sub-component to render depending on the url. Something like (`app.component.html`):

```
<main [ngSwitch]="currentPath">
  <foo-component *ngSwitchCase="/foo"></foo-component>
  <bar-component *ngSwitchCase="/bar"></bar-component>
</main>
```

And all Angular related pages would return html with just `<main-app></main-app>`.

However this solution feels hacky compared to simply declaring components in the server templates.

Comment: Please, explain your case further. What is this *turns out all root components must be declared in the html at once* supposed to mean? Why are they declared at once?

Comment: If all the pages have a common url prefix, you can use the [angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Comment: @estus If you list multiple root components in the module's bootstrap meta property angular will require all of them to be declared in the main html. In my use case each page contains only one component and components on each page differ from each other. Each page gets rendered by server, it's not a spa.

Comment: That's correct. You will need to have a separate module for each entry point then. Since it's cumbersome, ngSwitch is likely a better option.

Comment: @estus Thanks. If I have multiple modules for each page, which module will be a root module in that case? What would `main.ts` bootstrap? Or do you mean a separate app for each page with it's own `main.ts`?

Comment: All of them will be root modules. You will need to switch between them in bootstrapModule or have several main.ts files.